# How can we build a windows / WCF service for starting WEB API Channel for OSCOVA Bot

Tags: windows, wcf, windows-services, chatbot

I am trying to build a windows based OSCOVA Bot service using Syn.Bot and Syn.Bot Channels. I am trying to find some tutorials or links over the internet which can help me out. Currently there are a number of problems which I am facing. Like packages have compatibility issues.

While installing the service the error log says :

```
Microsoft (R) .NET Framework Installation utility Version 4.8.3761.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Running a transacted installation.

Beginning the Install phase of the installation.
See the contents of the log file for the D:\IntallService\Service\SIMLWinServices.exe assembly's 
progress.
The file is located at D:\IntallService\Service\SIMLWinServices.InstallLog.
Installing assembly 'D:\IntallService\Service\SIMLWinServices.exe'.
Affected parameters are:
logtoconsole =
assemblypath = D:\IntallService\Service\SIMLWinServices.exe
logfile = D:\IntallService\Service\SIMLWinServices.InstallLog
Installing service Service1...
Creating EventLog source Service1 in log Application...

An exception occurred during the Install phase.
System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot open Service Control Manager on computer '.'. This operation 
might require other privileges.
The inner exception System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception was thrown with the following error message: 
Access is denied.

The Rollback phase of the installation is beginning.
See the contents of the log file for the D:\IntallService\Service\SIMLWinServices.exe assembly's 
progress.
The file is located at D:\IntallService\Service\SIMLWinServices.InstallLog.
Rolling back assembly 'D:\IntallService\Service\SIMLWinServices.exe'.
Affected parameters are:
   logtoconsole =
   assemblypath = D:\IntallService\Service\SIMLWinServices.exe
   logfile = D:\IntallService\Service\SIMLWinServices.InstallLog
Restoring event log to previous state for source Service1.

The Rollback phase completed successfully.

The transacted install has completed.
The installation failed, and the rollback has been performed.
```

Answer (score 1):

During the installation of Windows NT services, we need to start the system management tool or access a specific folder, this requires execution privilege elevation.
I believe the error is due to insufficient rights during the installation. Therefore I suggest you run the command prompt as administrator, you can try the built-in CMD provided by Visual Studio.
[image]
Besides, please refer to the below link, wish it is useful to you.
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4bbeae09-d512-4728-b369-0c540d1625a4/cannot-open-service-control-manager-on-computer-this-operation-might-require-other-privileges?forum=netfxbcl
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/1c0bc374-c03f-4a46-9e53-d0b4c57b7d50/cannot-open-service-control-manager-on-computer-this-operation-might-require-other-privileges?forum=projectprofessional2010general
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.